# sudo port selfupdate never succeeds

Tags: macports

I'm trying to do this:

```
sudo port install nautilus
```

but it tells me

```
Error: Port nautilus not found
```

despite nautilus being clearly on MacPorts: http://rsync.macports.org/nautilus/. So, I attempt to do this:

```
sudo port -d selfupdate
```

and I get this:

```
DEBUG: Copying /Users/BL185083/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
DEBUG: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

And I checked to make sure my firewall was off:

[image: The Mac OS 'Security & Privacy' preference pane, on the 'Firewall' tab, indicating it's off.]

So... **Why can't I use MacPorts?**

Comment: The rsync server seems to be working fine from here, so I'm inclined to believe this is a problem with your local network (e.g. your network administrator filtering port 873 outbound). See http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#selfupdatefails for potential workarounds.

Comment: @neverpanic Alternatively, is there any way to access the software on MacPorts without using the command-line utility? e.g. traditional HTTP downloads?

Comment: Yes, these methods are mentioned at the end of the FAQ section I linked above. You can use SVN over HTTPS or a daily HTTP tarball (which is a waste of bandwidth though, so use SVN unless that doesn't work either).